# Spying on instance variable and return the value when instance function get calls

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock class instance and then return the mock object when we call the instance function but in result, it makes an actual call to function.

Here is my code:

```
AuthenticationSessionModel authSessionCookie =
    new AuthenticationSessionManager(session)
       .getCurrentAuthenticationSession(realm, client, tabId);
```

and my test code is:

```
AuthenticationSessionManager spyAuthSessionManager =
    Mockito.spy(new AuthenticationSessionManager(session));
        
doReturn(authenticationSessionModel)
    .when(spyAuthSessionManager)
    .getCurrentAuthenticationSession(any(), any(), anyString());
```

It makes an actual call to getCurrentAuthenticationSession() and returns me Null Pointer Exception

Comment: You should use `Mockito.mock` instead of `Mockito.spy` if you want to avoid calls to the real instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test, you create a spy, and stub some behaviour.
But you don't use that spy in the code under test.

Instead, in the code under test you create a new AuthenticationSessionManager.

You need to restructure your code and:

- create AuthenticationSessionManager outside of object under test.
- pass it to object under test. Constructor is the first thing that comes to mind.

With these changes, it becomes trivial to substitute a real AuthenticationSessionManager with a spy in a test.

Comment: what do you mean by outside of object under test? can you give me one example

Comment: Your code retrieving authSessionCookie is part of some method (method under test) in some object (object under test). Make `authenticationSessionManager` a field of this object, and an argument to the constructor. Pass authenticationSessionManager to the constructor.